# why "des von der" and not "von der"?

Tags: grammar-identification

Can anyone explain to me why *des* was put in this sentence?

> Im Zuge **des** von der Bundesregierung schrittweise geplanten Atomausstiegs wird nun aber auch der Meiler Winden vom Netz gehen müssen.

For me the sentence would make more sense without it.

Comment: Which sense would the sentence make without the "des"?

Answer (score 7):

You could shorten the sentence to

> Im Zuge **des Atomausstiegs** ...

Then, more and more detail about the *Atomausstieg* is added by inserting modifiers (*Attribute*):

> Im Zuge **des** *geplanten* **Atomausstiegs** ...
> Im Zuge **des** *schrittweise* geplanten **Atomausstiegs** ...
> Im Zuge **des** *von der Bundesregierung* schrittweise geplanten **Atomausstiegs** ...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a shorter version of this sentence, only the relevant parts are left unchanged:

> Im Zuge des von der Bundesregierung schrittweise geplanten Atomausstiegs wird *etwas geschehen.*
> <sub>*Something will happen* in the course of the nuclear phase-out planned step by step by the German government.</sub>

This is main clause without any add-ons:

> Etwas wird geschehen.
> <sub>Something will happen.</sub>

Let's attach the first add-on:

> Etwas wird **im Zuge *des* Atomausstiegs** geschehen.
> <sub>Something will happen **in the course *of the* nuclear phase-out.**</sub>

Here the article *"des"* appears. In English it becomes two words: *"of the".*

In German sentences the first position of a sentence is available for any part of speech (not only for the subject like in English), so we can move the new add-on to this place. But then the subject (etwas/something) must move to the position behind the verb. This maneuver is not possible in English, so the English translation will be the same:

> **Im Zuge *des* Atomausstiegs** wird etwas geschehen.
> <sub>Something will happen **in the course *of the* nuclear phase-out.**</sub>

Time for add-on #2:

> Im Zuge *des* Atomausstiegs, **der von der Bundesregierung geplant ist,** wird etwas geschehen.
> <sub>Something will happen in the course *of the* nuclear phase-out **which is planned by the German government.**</sub>

This new add-on is a relative clause describing the noun *Atomausstieg* (*nuclear phase-out*). But we can make it more elegant by turning it into a left attribute of this noun in German and a right attribute in English. The left attribute must stand immediately before the noun, i.e. between article and noun:

> Im Zuge *des* **von der Bundesregierung geplanten** Atomausstiegs wird etwas geschehen.
> <sub>Something will happen in the course *of the* nuclear phase-out **planned by the German government.**</sub>

The last add-on is just the cherry on the cake. It's an attribute of the praticiple *geplanten* (planned), and again it's a left attribute in German and a right attribute in English:

> Im Zuge *des* von der Bundesregierung **schrittweise** geplanten Atomausstiegs wird etwas geschehen.
> <sub>Something will happen in the course *of the* nuclear phase-out planned **step by step** by the German government.</sub>

Without the article *"des"* (*of the*), the sentence just will be wrong:

> **falsch:** Im Zuge von der Bundesregierung schrittweise geplanten Atomausstiegs wird etwas geschehen.
> <sub>**wrong:** Something will happen in the course nuclear phase-out planned step by step by the German government.</sub>